# Change service startup "sequence" with puppet

Tags: puppet, runlevel

When using

```
service { 'ntp':
  ensure     => running,
  enable     => true,
  # [...]
}
```

puppet will make sure, that the service will start on boot. Therefore it is creating links for several run levels (*/etc/rcN.d*) like `S20ntp`.

What would be a convenient puppet configuration to change the sequence number `20` to whatever (i.e. `30`)? I would like to avoid an `exec` type.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running.  These days almost everything is using some kind of dependency calculator to build the appropriate links.  Trying to force a value improperly would just get changed if some other package got installed.  You may need to update the LSB stanza in the init script to require the service you want to already be running (ie Required-Start).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't take this into consideration. Obviously this means, changing content of an _upstream_-installed script using puppet. On the first glance, this feels not good.   
Basically I run on an Ubuntu and (later on) CentOS system.